# Writing different objects with same values to a table with JPA and Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, kotlin, jpa, persistence, micronaut-data

Sorry for the long explanation in advance, I have been searching for similar issues to no avail.

I have two Tables, let's call them `Table A` and `Table B`

A has a foreign key Association with B i.e. Table B's `tB_id` value is a `foreign key` in Table A

Code Reference

`TableA`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tableA")
data class TableA(
    @Id @Column(name = "id") val id: String,
    @Column(name = "name") val name: String,
    @ManyToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL])
    @JoinColumn(name = "tB_id", referencedColumnName = "tB_id", nullable = false)
    val table2: Table2,
)
```

`TableB`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tableB")
data class TableB(
    @Id @Column(name = "tB_id") val tB_id: String,
    @Column(name = "name") val name: String,
)
```

`Issue`

I tried creating a list of objects of TableA and saving them

```
val x = listOf(TableA("id1","name1",TableB("idB1","nameB1"),
TableA("id2","name2",TableB("idB1","nameB1"))
tableARepo.saveAll(x)
```

It throws an error saying
`A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session` since it does not understand that both the objects are the same (atleast data wise)

`What works`

If I extract the TableB object out and pass the reference instead, the code (test) works
I can't use it since this is a list of data sent by users that is converted to a list of `TableA` objects

`Question`

- Is there a way for me to save the object using saveAll() in the current structure ?
- Is there a another alternative where I don't have to destructure the input List ?

Comment: No, that's not possible.

Comment: Hey, @SimonMartinelli Would you mind elaborating a little what prevents it from working as specified ? I looked at the implementation of hibernate (for code pieces I used) and it looks more like a missing feature ( assuming there is no alternative to what I did )

Comment: It may work if you implement equals

Comment: I did try that and it didn't work.

Comment: I think I answered your question extensively on discourse: https://discourse.hibernate.org/t/a-different-object-with-the-same-identifier-value-was-already-associated-with-the-session/6612